# File too big to open in R?

Tags: r

Hi one additional question. I've managed to open my files from excel into R by converting them into text files. The problem is that they are very large files, pushing the limits of excel. I now get this error in R. Any idea how i can work around it?

[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 463885 rows ]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a warning telling you that not all the data was displayed. It's still probably loading. You get the same when trying to display large matrices or data frames. For example you will get the same warning if you try `matrix(nrow=10000000)`

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin is spot on: Warning != error.  Try

```
 summary(myDataVar)

 dim(myDataVar)

 str(myDataVar)
```

for more.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the error you're getting, I think your data loaded into R just fine, but R has a limit on how many rows of data it will print to the console. Which makes sense - you probably don't want to sift through a half-million rows on a text terminal.

You can check the actual size of your object with the dim() function, to see how many rows R thinks are there.

Answer (score 1):

One useful trick is to run `str(data)`, where `data` is the name of your variable. This will display the layout of the structure that's been loaded, *including the number of rows*. The latter will tell you if the entire file has been loaded.